# Buy Php in Malaysia and sell to Philippines

Tags: foreign-exchange, currency, foreign-currency

I am a Filipino working in Malaysia. I went to the remittance center yesterday, the exchange is `MYR 1 = PHP 11.20`. I noticed the buy/sell board table. Buying Php for MYR 8.52, Selling MYR 8.98.

I do stock investing but I am an outsider to Forex. Why are they selling it way beyond the exchange rate? Why is this?

This means before going back to Philippines, I can buy a lot of peso that I can buy and exchange it for higher price right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I noticed the buy/sell board table.

Where did you notice this.

Generally for a pair of currencies, there is Unit associated along with direction. The Unit is generally constant. These are only revised when there is large devaluation of a particular currency.

> Buying Php for MYR 8.52, Selling MYR 8.98.

So in this case the Unit of PHP is 100, so Bank is Buying 100 PHP from you [you are selling PHP] and will give you MYR 8.52.

If you now want to buy 100 PHP [so the Bank is selling you], you have to pay MYR 8.98.

So you loose MYR 0.46

> Why are they selling it way beyond the exchange rate? Why is this?

As explained above, they are not. Its still within the range. The quote on internet are average price.

> This means before going back to Philippines, I can buy a lot of peso that I can buy and exchange it for higher price right?

Generally an individual cannot make money by buying in one currency and selling in other. There are specialist who try and find arbitrage between multiple pair of currencies and make money out of it. Its a continuous process, if they start making profit, the market will react and put pressure on a pair and the prices would move to remove the arbitrage.

Answer (score -3):

basically the selling (for banks) means you will exchange PHP to MYR
buying simply MYR to PHP

the bank will buy your MYR in exchange to PHP.

and you will sell your MYR to PHP.

I think it has something to do with processing fee..